# How do I get multiple hprof dumps in a Java WebStart (JNLP) application?

Tags: java, profiling, hprof

Working with a Java console application, I can do this:

```
java -agentlib:hprof=heap=dump,format=b MyClass
```

Then I can hit ctrl-\ (or ctrl-break on Windows) any time I would like to take a snapshot of the heap for later analysis.

I would like to do the same thing for a Java Web Start application, but I cannot seem to get that to work.  I can pass in the agentlib argument with the JAVAWS_VM_ARGS environment variable, but entering ctrl-\ and ctrl-break in the console doesn't seem to do anything.  All I get is one dump, when the program starts, which isn't really interesting since at that point I haven't even logged into our program yet and executed the transactions I want to analyze.

Answer (score 1):

Start your application with the following JMV arguments to enable JMX and boot a listener on port 9004:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port="9004"
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate="false"
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl="false"
```

Then have a look at this Java program which can make a connection to the JMX server and take a heap dump on demand.  The source code includes comments with links to 2 useful articles on the internet that helped me get all of this working.  Good luck !

Link: [JmxHeapDumper.java](http://code.google.com/p/perfbench/source/browse/trunk/perfbench/jmeter-utils/src/main/java/jmeterutils/JmxHeapDumper.java)

P.S. apparently getting JMX to start for a WebStart app is tricky, I found this discussion, hope it helps: http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=311717

Answer (score 0):

You could use [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) to take heap dumps from the running application. VisualVM lets you browse and save the heap dumps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems our Java Web Start application crashes when I try to profile its memory with VisualVM.